# SQL Server 2016 - ReportServer - sp_BlitzCache

Tags: sql-server-2016, sp-blitzcache

Does it ever make sense to try to tune queries in the ReportServer database behind SSRS? Diagnostic tools such as sp_BlitzCache indicate possible issues, but I've a tendency not to futz with that particular database. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can poke and prod much of the `ReportServer` DDL without adversely impacting your reports (if you know what you're doing). But I'd recommend not tweaking anything unless you're experiencing an actual symptomatic issue. "_Shows up on diagnostic scan_" wouldn't quite meet my bar - but that's very much an off-the-cuff opinion. If you're concerned - you can always consider posting the `sp_BlitzCache` output as a part of your question.

Comment: What Peter said -- also, I'm cool with adding ReportServer to the list of excluded 'system' databases by default, but it's never really been a pressing matter. If you'd like to open an issue about it, head over [here](http://firstresponderkit.org).

Comment: Thanks for the good advice, gentlemen. Erik, I opted to follow your suggestion and add ReportServer to the "system" databases.